# .Net Core 3.1 - Exception Using HttpClient's Content.ReadAsStringAsync() On Large Text File

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

We're making an API call with .NET Core 3.1 to download and read the contents of a text file. Our code works 99% of the time, but there is one very large 300 MB file that is throwing an exception.

This is the code we're using to download the file:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"raw/{repoPath}?at={branch}");
var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

And this is the code that reads the contents:

```
var codeContent = resp.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

With the 300 MB file, this throws the exception: "Error while copying content to a stream."
Inner exception is: "The response ended prematurely."

Is there a proven way to process the contents of such a large text file?

Comment: "The response ended prematurely" -> this is an issue in your server not in your client. 300MB is not really that big, but downloading on a slow connection is likely to fail intermittently

Comment: why are you calling `ReadAsStringAsync` synchronously?

Comment: @IanKemp We need the string contents before the next set of logic runs. It's just an API making a call to another API.

Comment: What is the content-type of the response?

Comment: Then you do not understand how async/await works. I strongly suggest you consult the official docs on MSDN.

Comment: @Michael Content-Type is application/json.

Comment: @IanKemp, I agree that he should use `await` instead of `.Result`, but I don't think it is the root of the problem he is facing.